# Get date object from difference between 2 dates, timezone dependant

Tags: php

I have a date stored in a database with timezone UTC, the date is a few days/hours/minutes ahead of right now.
I then need to calculate the difference in time between right now and the given date, bearing in mind that there could be different timezones at play.

I have been doing the following but it is wrong as the timezone isn't taken into consideration.

```
$interval = date_create('now')->diff(date_create($listing_end_date));
//$interval->d = days
//$interval->h = hours
//$interval->i = minutes
```

How can I do the above with the timezone taken into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a second argument to `date_create` telling it what time zone is represented by the date in `$listing_end_date`.  For example, assuming the string is in UTC:

```
$interval = date_create('now')->diff(date_create($listing_end_date, 
                                                 new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
```

Comment: or: $interval = date_create('now', DateTimeZone::UTC)->diff(date_create($listing_end_date, DateTimeZone::UTC))

Comment: @hsmoore.com - the question says the date in the database is UTC. There is no time zone to worry about with 'now' - now is now.

Comment: date_create() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, integer given

Comment: take `new DateTimeZone('UTC')` instead

Comment: @danlee - thanks, updated.  Sorry, just assumed that the predefined constants would be useful for something. :)